# Removing indices according to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list `J1` and a numpy array `inv_r`. I want to remove elements in `inv_r` according to indices in `J1`. I present the current and expected output.

```
import numpy as np

J1 = [[1, 3, 7, 9, 10]]
inv_r = np.array([[19371.82250346, 20264.94910211, 19697.49114878, 20151.47031158,
                   19899.73292203, 19912.05009437, 19567.94111435, 20777.21170365,
                   19525.03386252, 20375.7252995, 20397.43278826, 19371.82250346]])

inv_rJ1 = [inv_r[0][idx-1] for idx in J1[0]]
print(inv_rJ1)
```

The current output is

```
[19371.82250346, 19697.49114878, 19567.94111435, 19525.03386252, 20375.7252995]
```

The expected output is

```
[19371.82250346,19697.49114878, 19899.73292203, 19912.05009437, 19567.94111435,19525.03386252, 19371.82250346]
```

Comment: `np.delete(inv_r, J1[0])`